# Add a field to a ".where" statement after I use it to retrieve a relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I am currently trying to get all the listings from a user's friends (array) AND the user themselves.

I have tried:

```
 ids = current_user.friends << current_user
 @listings = Listing.where(:user_id => ids)
```

but when I use this heroku is crashing. Fundamentally what i want to get is

```
@listings = Listing.where(:user_id => current_user.friends OR :user_id => current_user)
```

How can we get this to happen?

Comment: did you tried `ids = current_user.friends << current_user` and `@listings = Listing.where('user_id in (?)', ids)` this?

Comment: Why are you including `current_user` into `current_user.friends`? Surely that would create infinite recursion?

Comment: @RichPeck I'm adding it to the array thats returned from the current_user.friends method. So basically inserting another entry into the array of friends.

Comment: @rony36 Yep tried that, unfortunately for some reason my server kept on freaking out about the fact that i was using a whole user object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in two ways. By array of ids or array of object it self. Not active record object. Because it's not appending object properly if you use active record object.

Considering friends are also from user table.

```
ids = current_user.friends.to_a << current_user
@listings = Listing.where(:user_id => ids)
```

or

```
ids = current_user.friends.pluck(:id).to_a << current_user.id
@listings = Listing.where(:user_id => ids)
```

If friends id fetch from other table called friends with one to many association then.

```
ids = current_user.friends.pluck(:user_id).to_a << current_user.id
@listings = Listing.where(:user_id => ids)
```

Comment: Use #pluck method to get only ids from table. current_user.friends.to_a will perform SELECT * FROM users and current_user.friends.pluck(:id) will perform only SELECT id FROM users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass array of IDs, try this

```
@listings = Listing.where("user_id IN (?)", current_user.friends.pluck(:user_id))
```